# VTK: Rotate actor programmatically while vtkRenderWindowInteractor is active

Tags: c++, vtk

I'm trying to rotate a `vtkActor` using `vtkActor::RotateZ` and then calling `vtkRenderWindow::Render`. It works fine (it rotates the actor) but I can't move, resize, or even focus the window.

I suspected this was caused due to something not catching operating system events, so I added a `vtkRenderWindowInteractor` to the mix. Now I can move, resize and focus the window, but the actor is not rotating anymore.

I've isolated the code in the snippet below, comment line 43 to see both effects:

```
renderWindowInteractor->Start();
```

I'm compiling VTK 6.2 with mingw-w64 (GCC 4.9.1), running in Windows 8.1. I've uploaded the code in [this repo](https://github.com/Blito/VTK-SFML/tree/4beb980eff21bc8ce6e9f83db6840a8778dbf56f) with a small CMake setup so you can test it easily.

Thanks for your help!

---

```
constexpr float planeWidth = 200.0f;
constexpr float planeHeight = 100.0f;

int main()
{
    auto renderer = vtkRenderer::New();

    // Create render window
    auto renWin = vtkRenderWindow::New();
    renWin->AddRenderer(renderer);
    renWin->SetSize(600,600);

    // Create a plane
    auto texturedPlane = vtkActor::New();
    auto plane = vtkPlaneSource::New();
    plane->SetOrigin(0, planeHeight, 0);
    plane->SetPoint1(planeWidth, planeHeight, 0);
    plane->SetPoint2(0, 0, 0);

    auto planeMapper = vtkPolyDataMapper::New();
    planeMapper->SetInputConnection(plane->GetOutputPort());
    texturedPlane->SetMapper(planeMapper);
    texturedPlane->SetOrigin(planeWidth / 2, planeHeight, 0);

    renderer->AddActor(texturedPlane);
    renderer->ResetCamera();

    // Create a RenderWindowInteractor
    auto renderWindowInteractor = vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renWin);
    renderWindowInteractor->Start(); // <-- Comment this line!

    // Render
    float rot = 0.0f;
    while(true)
    {
        texturedPlane->SetOrientation(0,0,0);
        texturedPlane->RotateZ(rot++);

        renWin->Render();
    }
}
```

---

**Solved using asdfasdf's solution:**
(Code in [this repo](https://github.com/Blito/VTK-SFML/blob/stackoverflow-question/main.cpp))

```
constexpr float planeWidth = 200.0f;
constexpr float planeHeight = 100.0f;
vtkActor * texturedPlane;
vtkRenderWindowInteractor * renderWindowInteractor;
vtkRenderWindow * renWin;
float rot = 0.0f;

class RotateCommand : public vtkCommand
{
public:
    vtkTypeMacro(RotateCommand, vtkCommand);

    static RotateCommand * New()
    {
        return new RotateCommand;
    }

    void Execute(vtkObject * vtkNotUsed(caller),
                 unsigned long vtkNotUsed(eventId), 
                 void * vtkNotUsed(callData))
    {
        texturedPlane->SetOrientation(0,0,0);
        texturedPlane->RotateZ(rot++);

        renWin->Render();
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto renderer = vtkRenderer::New();

    // Create render window
    renWin = vtkRenderWindow::New();
    renWin->AddRenderer(renderer);
    renWin->SetSize(600,600);

    // Create a plane
    texturedPlane = vtkActor::New();
    auto plane = vtkPlaneSource::New();
    plane->SetOrigin(0, planeHeight, 0);
    plane->SetPoint1(planeWidth, planeHeight, 0);
    plane->SetPoint2(0, 0, 0);

    auto planeMapper = vtkPolyDataMapper::New();
    planeMapper->SetInputConnection(plane->GetOutputPort());
    texturedPlane->SetMapper(planeMapper);
    texturedPlane->SetOrigin(planeWidth / 2, planeHeight, 0);

    renderer->AddActor(texturedPlane);

    renderer->ResetCamera();

    // Create a RenderWindowInteractor
    renderWindowInteractor = vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renWin);
    renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();
    renderWindowInteractor->CreateRepeatingTimer(1);
    RotateCommand * rotateCallback =  RotateCommand::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->AddObserver(vtkCommand::TimerEvent, rotateCallback );

    renderWindowInteractor->Start();
}
```

Comment: If you need to use the interactor as well as rotating the object, you should try using a callback method on the interactor, which will rotate your plane at each x time. See this example : http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/CommandSubclass

the problem is that as soon as you will start interacting with the window, the plane will stop rotating until you stop interacting with the window again.

To make it short, you will be able to interact and rotate, but just one at a time.

Comment: Is there any way not to use the Interactor and still be able to move, resize and focus the window? I don't really need it, it was the only way I found that let me drag the window on my screen.

Comment: I'm sorry for the late reply, I will let you know what I did, it's more of a hack than anything else, and it still has the problem I told you. And yes, you need the interactor if you want to play with the window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hack to get around part of the problem.

```
vtkRenderWindowInteractor * renderWindowInteractor;
constexpr float planeWidth = 200.0f;
constexpr float planeHeight = 100.0f;

class CommandSubclass2 : public vtkCommand
{
  public:
    vtkTypeMacro(CommandSubclass2, vtkCommand);

    static CommandSubclass2 *New()
    {
        return new CommandSubclass2;
    }

    void Execute(vtkObject *vtkNotUsed(caller), unsigned long vtkNotUsed(eventId), 
                    void *vtkNotUsed(callData))
    {
        std::cout << "timer callback" << std::endl;
        renderWindowInteractor->ExitCallback();
    }
};

int main()
{
    auto renderer = vtkRenderer::New();

    // Create render window
    auto renWin = vtkRenderWindow::New();
    renWin->AddRenderer(renderer);
    renWin->SetSize(600,600);

    // Create a plane
    auto texturedPlane = vtkActor::New();
    auto plane = vtkPlaneSource::New();
    plane->SetOrigin(0, planeHeight, 0);
    plane->SetPoint1(planeWidth, planeHeight, 0);
    plane->SetPoint2(0, 0, 0);

    auto planeMapper = vtkPolyDataMapper::New();
    planeMapper->SetInputConnection(plane->GetOutputPort());
    texturedPlane->SetMapper(planeMapper);
    texturedPlane->SetOrigin(planeWidth / 2, planeHeight, 0);

    renderer->AddActor(texturedPlane);
    renderer->ResetCamera();

    // Create a RenderWindowInteractor
    renderWindowInteractor = vtkRenderWindowInteractor::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->SetRenderWindow(renWin);

    renderWindowInteractor->Initialize();
    renderWindowInteractor->CreateRepeatingTimer(1);

    vtkSmartPointer<CommandSubclass2> timerCallback =  vtkSmartPointer<CommandSubclass2>::New();
    renderWindowInteractor->AddObserver ( vtkCommand::TimerEvent, timerCallback );


    // Render
    float rot = 0.0f;
    while(true)
    {
        renderWindowInteractor->Start(); // <-- Comment this line!
        texturedPlane->SetOrientation(0,0,0);
        texturedPlane->RotateZ(rot++);           
        renWin->Render();
    }
}
```

I'm sorry if I didn't give you any other reply, but since this solution is quite bad, I was waiting for someone else to find a better solution, but it seems that no one answered you, so here is what I would do.

You can pretty much guess what it does. Each 1 ms after starting the interaction, a callback is called that will stop the interaction, and do a rotation.

Comment: even better : don't do this `while(true)` loop, and just do your rotation in the callback method, without calling `exitcallback()` and `start()` multiple times

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I'll try that and get back to you. The `while(true)` was just for this example, but you're right.

Comment: I'm just not sure if you can call the `Render()` method in the callback, but I will let you test this one. :)

Comment: It worked! I got rid of the `while(true)` and also was able to call `Render()` from the callback. Code can be found in [my repo](https://github.com/Blito/VTK-SFML/blob/stackoverflow-question/main.cpp). I'll edit my post with it.

Comment: Take a look at this example: http://www.vtk.org/Wiki/VTK/Examples/Cxx/Utilities/Animation